# can't update radio buttons on database and html page

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have "Customers" table that I use to insert data and update data. one thing that I can't update is radio buttons. for example - when I register a new customer to database radio buttons and all fields works great. when I enter a specific customer to change his details - all details are updated with no problmes except when I try to ***update*** the radio buttons - I can't update because its deleting for unknown reason the radio buttons information from database and from html. can anyone help?

this is my code:

Php for updateing customer:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hamatkin");

  include_once 'Customer.php';
mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_results = utf8");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo "Called @ ".
            xdebug_call_file().
            ":".
            xdebug_call_line().
            " from ".
            xdebug_call_function();

//$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo "Mydata -> " .$_POST["customer_id"];


// $sql_statement = "Update customers set full_name = '" .$_POST["Full_name"] ."', id=" .$_POST["Id"]  ." where customer_id = " .$_POST["customer_id"];
$sql_statement = "Update customers set kind_Of_Customer='" .$_POST["kind_Of_Customer"] ."', full_name = '" .$_POST["full_name"] ."', id=" .$_POST["id"] .",city='" .$_POST["city"] ."',
address='" .$_POST["adress"] ."', phone='" .$_POST["phone"] ."',phone_2='" .$_POST["phone_2"] ."',email='" .$_POST["email"] ."',
fax='" .$_POST["fax"] ."',referrer='" .$_POST["referrer"] ."',comments='" .$_POST["comments"] ."' where customer_id = " .$_POST["customer_id"];

 // $sql_statement = "Update customers set full_name = '" .$_POST["full_name"] ."', id=" .$_POST["id"]  ." where customer_id = " .$_POST["customer_id"];
mysqli_query($con,$sql_statement);
// var_dump($_POST);

mysqli_close($con);
//echo $sql_statement;


// טעינה של הטופש מחדש לאחר לחיצה על כפתור אישור
$newURL = "/hamatkin/#/customerCards";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
?>
```

Php for getting specific customer details:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    include_once 'Customer.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');

    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_results = utf8");

// יצירת אובייקט לקוח חדש
    $customer = new Customer();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers where customer_id= " .$_GET["Id"];
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if( $result->num_rows!=0)
    {

        $customer->customer_id = $row['customer_id'];
        $customer->kind_Of_Customer = $row['kind_Of_Customer'];
        $customer->full_name =$row['full_name'];
        $customer->id = $row['id'];
        $customer->city = $row['city'];
        $customer->address = $row['address'];
        $customer->phone = $row['phone'];
        $customer->phone_2 = $row['phone_2'];
        $customer->email = $row['email'];
        $customer->fax = $row['fax'];
        $customer->referrer = $row['referrer'];
        $customer->comments = $row['comments'];
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM orders where refer_customer_id= " .$_GET["Id"];
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $customer->orders = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $customer->orders[] = $row;
    }

    //echo print_r($customer); die;
    $res = json_encode($customer);
     echo $res;
?>
```

html for the radio buttons

```
  <div class="form-group">
          <label>איך הופנה אלינו:</label>
          <div class="c-input c-radio">
              <input id="refferer" name="refferer" value="פייסבוק" type="radio" ng-model="customerDetails.refferer" >
              <span class="c-indicator"></span>
              פייסבוק
          </div>
          <div class="c-input c-radio">
              <input id="refferer" name="refferer" value="גוגל" type="radio" ng-model="customerDetails.refferer"  >
              <span class="c-indicator"></span>
              גוגל
          </div>
          <div class="c-input c-radio">
              <input id="refferer" name="refferer" value="חברים"  type="radio"  ng-model="customerDetails.refferer" >
              <span class="c-indicator"></span>
             חברים
          </div>
        </div>
```